# Django: How to create a Group through a command?

Tags: django

I want to automate all the data creation on my data base, for this I'm using different commands.

I know how to do this for my models, because I know its fields.

**But how to do this for Group model?**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
```

When I query its fields I get: **'user', 'id', 'name', 'permissions'**

```
[f.name for f in Group._meta.get_fields()]
```

But in Admin Panel I only See that in order to create a Group the `name` and the `permission` fields are required:

**command**:

```
import pandas as pd
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand



tmp_data_groups=pd.read_csv('static/data/groups.csv',sep=',', encoding='iso-8859-1').fillna(" ")



class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        groups = [
            Group(
                name=row['name'],
                permissions=row['permissions']
        )
            for _, row in tmp_data_groups.iterrows()
        ]

        Group.objects.bulk_create(groups)
```

I get this error (with the command or in shell):

> TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set
>   is prohibited. Use permissions.set() instead.

**Example using the shell:**

I've a Group named "Clientes" and it has assigned all the permisions.

```
Group.objects.all()[0].permissions.all() #Clientes is the only group created
```

I wan to create a new group called "NuevosClientes" (NewClients in english).

```
Group.objects.create(name='NuevosClientes', permissions='Can view user')
```

Tried this but got:

```
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use permissions.set() instead.
```

**How should I prepare my CSV field to be read and to generate the desired new group using a command?**

```
| name           | permissions        |   |   |   |
|----------------|--------------------|---|---|---|
| NuevosClientes | Can view user      |   |   |   |
| NuevosClientes | Can add permission |   |   |   |
| NuevosClientes | Can delete user    |   |   |   |
| NuevosClientes | Can delete cart    |   |   |   |
```

**UPDATE 1**:

I've created my groups, but now I need to create the Permissions to be added to these groups.

But in order to create the Permissions I also need to create the ContentType objects.

How ever, the ContentType object has these arguments.

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='app_name', model='model_name')
```

According to this asnwer in another post, everytime we create model an entry in the `django_content_type` table a new record is added in this table for said model.

> What entry should I use to create the ContentType object?
>   What should be the values for app_label='app_name' and model='model_name'?

There are a lot of entries in the `django_content_type` table:

```
`logentry`, `permission`, `group`, `user`, `contenttype`, `session`, and also for my own models.
```

Comment: You can only set values in an m2m relation *after* you crated the object. The form simply makes that more convenient.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the issue is that you need to create the `Group` object before you can add `permissions` to is because the internal table connecting them will need the pk for Group.  Try creating your group then using permissions.add for each row

Comment: @HenryM I'll try that approache. With this I'll need proable 2 commands to automate the creation of the groups and their permissions. I'll post the results in a few hours.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think that is the same HenryM mentions, please, confirm this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only add items to a many-to-many relation, if the objects that are related to that relation are already saved.

So you probably first want to save the `Group` you have constructed, and then add the permission. Note that [**`Permission`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Permission) is a model as well, so you can not just use a string here.

Your command will thus look like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

# ...

g1 = Group.objects.create(name=row['name'])
p1, __ = Permission.objects.get_or_create(name=row['permissions'])
g1.permissions.add(p1)
```

We thus first construct a `Group` object with a given name, then we retrieve the related `Permission` object, and then we add that permission `p1` to the `permissions` of the given group. If there can be multiple permissions, you will need to make it a bit more sophisticated.

You can still use `bulk_create` by performing two passes: first you construct all the groups with the given names, and then in a second pass you retrieve all the related permissions and set these correctly.

Comment: @OmarGonzales: you can not make assignments in a list comprehension clause. Furthermore as said before you need to do this in two passes. First create all the groups, for example with `bulk_create`, and then perform the linking, not interleaved.