# Django: how to create a ContentType Object for a Permission?

Tags: django

I'm trying to create in the backend Groups and Permissions.

Now I'm trying to understand what is the `content_type` argument and how to use it when creating a Permission.

[Documentation for Permission model says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#id1):

> content_type¶
>
> Required. A reference to the django_content_type database table, which contains a record for each installed model.

**How can I get this content_type? Where should I look for it?**

I'm using PosgresSQL as Database.

According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831933/how-can-dynamically-create-permission-in-django), one can do this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='app_name', model='model_name')
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_create_hr',
                                       name='Can create HR',
                                       content_type=content_type) # creating permissions
group = Group.objects.get(name='HR')
group.permissions.add(permission)
```

But again, what is `app_label='app_name', model='model_name'` inside:
`content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='app_name', model='model_name')`?

My project structure:

```
stickers-gallito-app
    |_cart
    |_shop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L57) it refers to the [**`ContentType`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType):

> ```
> class Permission(models.Model):
>
>     #  ...
>
>     name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
>     content_type = models.ForeignKey(
>         ContentType,
>         models.CASCADE,
>         verbose_name=_('content type'),
>     )
>     codename = models.CharField(_('codename'), max_length=100)
> ```

A `ContentType` is a model to refer to model classes. If you install the `contentype` app, then Django will maintain such table and "maintain" it: this means that if you add an extra model, Django will automatically add an entry to the `ContentType` model. You can see these values in your database (usually under the `django_content_type` table).

A model class is defined in an `app`, and that app has a label. Furthermore a model also has a name itself. For example for the `User` model, we see:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User._meta.app_label
'auth'
>>> User._meta.model_name
'user'
```

A model can thus be specified through the `app_label` and the `model_name`.

You can for example obtain a reference to the class of that content type through the [**`model_class`** method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType.model_class):

```
mypermission.content_type.model_class()
```

Comment: please see my update related to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989579/django-how-to-create-a-group-through-a-command

Comment: What is the logic for which record in `django_content_type` table to use when creating the Permission?

Comment: @OmarGonzales: in the cited question it is (very) likely that your `Permission`s already exist. You can search these by the `name` attribute. For example `Can add user` will already exist, and link to the `User` model, but that is irrelevant.